# Time Dependent workflow is not triggering mail based on the evaluation criteria

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

Hi I tried to develop time dependent work flow to trigger mail after 5 days of the case created date base on the condition IF priority = Normal and Status != Closed,Swap-shipped. I tried it in both " when a record is Created" and with " Whenever a record is Created and subsequently edited to meet the Criteria". However, on Day 5 [image] The email is getting triggered even IF the case status is = Closed.

Comment: Is there perhaps another timed workflow that might be triggering this? I see this one is based on Priority, do you have others that might be activating? So make sure you change is back to created, and anytime it's edited to meet criteria.

Comment: @stephen I have three more Time based triggers , however they do not have any connection with this.

Comment: Are you familiar with monitoring time based workflow?  As soon as you trigger the rule you can see the time trigger in the queue under setup - monitor - time based workflow.  And as soon as you set case to closed, you should see it removed.  Yoy can see which rule placed the time trigger in the queue so it should be clear. I would create a case, and monitor the queue.  Then update the case and see what if anything happens.  The config looks correct to me, the time triggers should be removed from the queue once you update status to closed.

Comment: @gorav Yes I would monitor the time based workflow. I choose the time based workflow and find list of case record that was scheduled to fire on the particular date. I manually checked all the records and found even the records that has the status = Closed were in the list.

Comment: Try one thing, remove the other statuses from the criteria and just include closed.  Then try again w a new case.  I would clear out the queue first, so it's all fresh, assuming you are in a sandbox.  Changing the criteria wont affect items already in the queue.

Comment: @gorav I did the testing however it worked fine. I created the case , It showed up the monitor-Time based workflow. And changed the status to closed. the Case is gone from the list. This was in sandbox, However We have this Issue in the prod Environment. Any Idea what would be the reason .

Comment: @gorav, I have one question Will the workflow be applicable for the case that created through a Web-to-case?

Comment: Yes i think the workflow should apply when created via Web to case, however not positive if it would apply if the case is closed upon creation.  In sandbox if you add the second case status does it still work?  If not Im just guessing that the / character might be causing the issue.  Try just with the second status and see how it works.

Comment: @gorav I did both way testing , with and without the Status.It worked in both ways fine in the sandbox.

Comment: Rule in prod was deployed from sandbox?  So it's exactly the same?  And as you can't deploy case status, you are positive that the value in filter is correct?  Any other code or rules in prod that are not in sb?  Maybe try spinning up a new sb from prod so it's an exact copy and test there?

Comment: @gorav I thought of saying will workflow be applicable for case that created through Email-to-case. Not web.

Comment: we use email to case w workflow, no issues. Note that when a new email comes in it won't trigger case workflows, you can do a cross object workflow on the email object to update the case and trigger case workflows.  Case creation via e2c should trigger case workflows.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `Evaluation criteria` to **created**. This means that your WR criteria are evaluated only when the record is created and never after. Change it to **created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria**

Comment: I tried that Evaluation as well. In fact that was the one I initially created,since I get the same Issue I changed it to Created.